# Running a Java program with input from a file

Tags: java, file, user-input, java.util.scanner

I am writing a program that reads the input from a file and then prints it to the screen. When I run it without taking the input from the file, it works perfectly fine. However, every time I try to run it from the file it gives me an "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found at" error that occurs every place the input is suppose to be read. I have no idea what is going on.

This program is suppose to take the input from the user, create a Photo object, and then print the information to the screen. Everything runs fine when I am entering the information manually but when I try to use java PhotoTest < test.dat to get the input for a file it gives this error message:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

  at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)

  at PhotoTest.readPhoto(PhotoTest.java:31)

  at PhotoTest.main(PhotoTest.java:74)

My code that has input:

```
private static Photo readPhoto(Scanner scanner) throws ParseException
{
    Date dateTaken;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String subject = scan.nextLine();
    subject = subject.trim();

    String location = scan.nextLine();
    location = location.trim();

    String date = scan.nextLine();
    date = date.trim();
        if (date.equals("")){ //if the date is empty it is set to null
            dateTaken = null;
            }
        else { //if a date is entered, it is then parsed
            DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
            dateTaken = df.parse(date);
            }

    String file = scan.nextLine();
    file = file.trim();
    File photoFile = new File(file);

    //creates a Photo object from the information entered
    Photo Photo = new Photo(subject, location, dateTaken, photoFile);

    return Photo;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
{
    boolean endprogram = false;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //creates  a loop so that the user may enter as many photos as they wish
    while (!endprogram)
    {
        System.out.println("Would you like to enter a photo (y/n)?");

        //if the input is anything other than y, the program ends
        if(!scan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            endprogram = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println(readPhoto(scan));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: is this the real code? it won't even compile if you don't return a Photo on the readPhoto method, also post the code that actually reads the file would help

Comment: @Katy: it's impossible to help you at this point. You need to be more clear of what your program is supposed to do. When presenting code, also make sure that it captures the essence of the question. Your current code has MANY problems that aren't even related to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Everything runs fine when I am entering the information manually but when I try to use `java PhotoTest < test.dat` to get the input for[sic?] a file [...]

Does `test.dat` contain the `"y"` confirmations too? When you pipe in a file for `stdin`, the content of that file must be in legal format as if it was typed in manually.

---

Also, you are creating another `Scanner` instance for `stdin` even though one is already passed to `readPhoto`. Are you sure you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your file you need a carriage return in the last line. That would be the equivalent to what you are typing manually. Note that when you are typing, in the last line you press enter.